# How to PHPUnit test a group function within Yii on Netbeans?

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, yii, phpunit

I've problem when I used PHPUnit test framework Yii in Netbeans.

I've a class DemoController.php extends from class Controller of Yii. And I've a class DemoControllerTest.php.

I can test all function in class by PHPUnit, but when I used `@group annotation` (support by PHPUnit) to test a group function. **It not runs**.

DemoController.php:

```
class DemoController extends Controller {
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

DemoControllerTest.php:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../fixtures/dataProvider.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../controllers/DemoController.php';

class DemoControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    protected $object;
    protected function setUp() {
        $this->object = new Calculator;
    }

     /**
     * @group Calculator
     * 
     * @dataProvider dataProvider
     */
    public function testCalculator($expectValue, $inputA, $inputB) {
        $this->assertEquals($expectValue, $this->object->add($inputA, $inputB));
    }

    function dataProvider(){
        $result = dataProvider::dataProvider();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And here is dataProvider.php:

```
class dataProvider {      
    static function dataProvider(){
        return array(
            array(0, 0, 0),
            array(0, 1, 1),
            array(1, 0, 1),
            array(1, 1, 3)
        );
    }     
}
```

Comment: What command are you using to run your tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use test groups in NetBeans you need to ensure that you have the settings configured correctly for your project. Ensure that your tests are annotated correctly with the group notation `@group group-name`. Then in your project properties ensure that the checkbox for test groups is checked.

[image: © 2012, Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates]

Then when you run your tests you will see a dialog popup with a selection of your groups.

[image: © 2012, Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates]

If you don't see the dialog box above when you press `Ctrl+F6` then try right clicking on the file and selecting `Test`. For more information see the [Netbeans PHPUnit documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html).