# Don't test groups( PHPUnit support @group annotation) functions of class extends from Yii in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, phpunit

Current I've a problem with Yii, when I'd using "`@group` annotation" ( *support by PHPUnit* ) to test a groups function in my class **extends** from Yii.

I'd configured as guidance in forum of Yii [(NetBeans IDE and Yii projects)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/83/netbeans-ide-and-yii-projects/).

I'd tested all functions in my class, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. **It runs very good**.

But when I'd used "`@group` annotation" (*support by PHPUnit*). **It doesn't run**, *I don't see the dialog box*.

When I check **"Ask for Test Groups Before Running Tests**" in dialog configure PHPUnit. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, I don't see the dialog box.

I thing this's problem here are two file "**bootstrap.php**" and "**phpunit.php**", but I don't how alter it?

I had question as it for forum Yii, and [demo code](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29896-dont-test-groups-phpunit-support-group-annotation-functions-of-class-extends-from-yii-in-netbeans/).

Comment: I suggest you try as well at the commandline as this will reveal more details (or if Netbeans PHPUnit integration support it: view the log/debug/console).

Comment: It run in the command line very good. But I wanted ran in Netbeans, because Netbeans PHPUnit support view error very good.

Comment: Sure, it's more comfortable, but I'm not a frequent Netbeans user, so I can not give you the real tips. Have you seen: [How to PHPUnit test a group function within Yii on Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731077/how-to-phpunit-test-a-group-function-within-yii-on-netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

**How to alter bootstrap.php or phpunit.xml?**
Just open in your favourite text editor, Netbeans will suffice. As to the meaning of these files, Referring to [phpunit documentation](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/#documentation) available in english, french and japanese it would seem.

> - bootstrap - A "bootstrap" PHP file that is run before the tests.

> - configuration - If phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist (in that order) exist in the current working directory and --configuration is not used, the configuration will be automatically read from that file.

I would not worry about bootstrap.php if you haven't needed it you probably won't and suffice to say nothing you can add there will improve the behaviour in Netbeans.

With regards to [configuring groups](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.groups) the phpunit documentation is quite elaborate:

> The <groups> element and its <include>, <exclude>, and <group> children can be used to select groups of tests from a suite of tests that should (not) be run.

> ```
>  <groups>
>     <include>
>         <group>name</group>
>     </include>
>     <exclude>
>         <group>name</group>
>     </exclude>
> </groups>
> ```

> The XML configuration above corresponds to invoking the TextUI test runner with the following switches:

> --group name

> --exclude-group name

Again nothing which would improve netbeans with regard to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> usage you are after, instead I would also suggest you refer to [Devin M's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731077/how-to-phpunit-test-a-group-function-within-yii-on-netbeans#answers-header) explanation, as @hakre already suggested, combine that with the [Netbeans - run test groups documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html#test-groups) and there is nothing more I could add still as it is complete, I am afraid.

Good luck and please let us know how things have turned out for you.

Comment: No matter how over-politely you tried to make it, your lengthy monologue on grammar is totally off topic;  particularly since there's a decent chance OP is not a native English speaker.  If you truly felt it was necessary, a "P.S. I struggled with understanding your grammar some, you might find you get better responses if you tidy that up" would have been more than sufficient.

Comment: @Boy'sRules would you mind giving us some feedback? What have you tried from the suggestions and what have you found? Is this still a problem? If the answer helped you please accept it and lets close this issue. Unfortunately there is nothing more we can add to this without further information from you.